# Bit Addressing in 8051

Tags: microcontroller, assembly, 8051, addressing

Can i only  use the MOV command (for bit addressable registers like PSW,ACC as well as ports ) with the carry bit?

Is the command :
MOV PSW.4,ACC.4 work with the assembler?
if not why?
How can i directly move a bit from one bit addressable loacation to the other and between SFRs?

```
;-----------------------------------
I am using EDSim51dI version 2.1.14
;----------------------------------
```

ALSO,
i am having problems using commands for bit addressing of PSW in the sim...!

EX: These instructions dont seem to work

```
org 0000h
mov psw,#0fh 
mov c,psw.4
```

please help?
Urgent..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to move individual bits around, you need to do it in two steps, storing the bit temporarily in the carry bit:

```
mov c, psw.4
mov acc.4, c
```